# How solve this errors in avrstudio

Tags: avr

### what can i do with this errors?

```
#ifndef WS2811_h
#define WS2811_h
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <WS2811.h>
```

### **Error 1   unterminated #ifndef**

```
 typedef struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
       uint8_t r;
       uint8_t g;
        uint8_t b;
    } RGB_t;
```

**Error 2   expected `':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before 'r'`**

please help me! thanks

---

**thanks for your help but it not worked!!!
the main code is here:**

```
/*
 * WS2811 RGB LED driver.
 */
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#ifndef WS2811_h
#define WS2811_h
#endif
#include <WS2811.h>


// RGB value structure.
typedef struct  __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
     uint8_t r;
     uint8_t g;
     uint8_t b;
}  RGB_t;

#ifndef ARRAYLEN
#define ARRAYLEN(A) (sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]))
#endif

/*
 * Inline asm macro to output 24-bit RGB value in (G,R,B) order, MSBit first.
 * 0 bits are 250ns hi, 1000ns lo, 1 bits are 1000ns hi, 250ns lo.
 * r18 = red byte to be output
 * r19 = green byte to be output
 * r20 = blue byte to be output
 * r26 = saved SREG
 * r27 = inner loop counter
 */
#define WS2811(PORT, PIN, RGB, LEN) \
asm volatile( \
/* initialise */ \
"    cp %A[len], r1      ; check len > 0, return immediately if it is\n" \
"    cpc %B[len], r1\n" \
"    brne 1f\n" \
"    rjmp 16f\n" \
"1:  ld r18, Z+           ; load in first red byte to be output\n" \
"    ld r19, Z+           ; load in first green byte to be output\n" \
"    ld r20, Z+           ; load in first blue byte to be output\n" \
"    ldi r27, 8           ; load inner loop counter\n" \
"    in r26, __SREG__     ; timing-critical, so no interrupts\n" \
"    cli\n" \
/* green - loop over 8 bits */ \
"2:  sbi  %[port], %[pin] ; pin lo -> hi\n" \
"    sbrc r19, 7          ; test hi bit clear\n" \
"    rjmp 3f              ; true, skip pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    cbi  %[port], %[pin] ; false, pin hi -> lo\n" \
"3:  sbrc r19, 7          ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
"    rjmp 4f\n" \
"4:  nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    lsl r19              ; shift to next bit\n" \
"    dec r27              ; decrement loop counter\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    brne 2b\n            ; loop if required\n" \
"    ldi r27, 7           ; reload inner loop counter\n" \
/* red - loop over first 7 bits */ \
"5:  sbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin lo -> hi\n" \
"    sbrc r18, 7          ; test hi bit clear\n" \
"    rjmp 6f              ; true, skip pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; false, pin hi -> lo\n" \
"6:  sbrc r18, 7          ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
"    rjmp 7f\n" \
"7:  nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    lsl r18              ; shift to next bit\n" \
"    dec r27              ; decrement inner loop counter\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    brne 5b              ; inner loop, if required\n" \
"    nop                  ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
/* red, 8th bit - output & fetch next values */ \
"    sbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin lo -> hi\n" \
"    sbrc r18, 7          ; test hi bit clear\n" \
"    rjmp 8f              ; true, skip pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; false, pin hi -> lo\n" \
"8:  sbrc r18, 7          ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
"    rjmp 9f\n" \
"9:  nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    ld r18, Z+           ; load next red byte\n" \
"    ld r19, Z+           ; load next green byte\n" \
"    ldi r27, 7           ; reload inner loop counter\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
/* blue - loop over first 7 bits */ \
"10:  sbi %[port], %[pin] ; pin lo -> hi\n" \
"    sbrc r20, 7          ; test hi bit clear\n" \
"    rjmp 11f             ; true, skip pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; false, pin hi -> lo\n" \
"11: sbrc r20, 7          ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
"    rjmp 12f\n" \
"12: nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    lsl r20              ; shift to next bit\n" \
"    dec r27              ; decrement inner loop counter\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    brne 10b             ; inner loop, if required\n" \
"    nop                  ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
/* blue, 8th bit -  output & handle outer loop */ \
"    sbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin lo -> hi\n" \
"    sbrc r20, 7          ; test hi bit clear\n" \
"    rjmp 13f             ; true, skip pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; false, pin hi -> lo\n" \
"13: sbrc r20, 7          ; equalise delay of both code paths\n" \
"    rjmp 14f\n" \
"14: nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    ldi r27, 8           ; reload inner loop counter\n" \
"    sbiw %A[len], 1      ; decrement outer loop counter\n" \
"    breq 15f             ; exit outer loop if zero\n" \
"    ld r20, Z+           ; load in next blue byte\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    rjmp 2b              ; outer loop, if required\n" \
"15: nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    cbi %[port], %[pin]  ; pin hi -> lo\n" \
"    nop                  ; pulse timing delay\n" \
"    nop\n" \
"    out __SREG__, r26    ; reenable interrupts\n" \
"16:\n" \
: \
: [rgb] "z" (RGB), \
  [len] "w" (LEN), \
  [port] "I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORT)), \
  [pin] "I" (PIN) \
: "r18", "r19", "r20", "r26", "r27", "cc", "memory" \
)

/*
 * Define a C function to wrap the inline WS2811 macro for a given port and pin.
 */
#define DEFINE_WS2811_FN(NAME, PORT, PIN) \
extern void NAME(const RGB_t *rgb, uint16_t len) __attribute__((noinline)); \
void NAME(const RGB_t *rgb, uint16_t len) { WS2811(PORT, PIN, rgb, len); }

#endif /* WS2811_h */

/*
 * Copyright 2012 Alan Burlison, alan@bleaklow.com.  All rights reserved.
 * Use is subject to license terms.
 *
 * Demo of the WS2811 driver, driving 3 pixels.
 */

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#define BIT(B)           (0x01 << (uint8_t)(B))
#define SET_BIT_HI(V, B) (V) |= (uint8_t)BIT(B)
#define SET_BIT_LO(V, B) (V) &= (uint8_t)~BIT(B)

#define PAUSE  1000     // msec
#define DELAY    10 // msec

// Define the output function, using pin 0 on port b.
DEFINE_WS2811_FN(WS2811RGB, PORTB, 0)

// Drive the three pixels in an infinit loop.
void threepixeldemo(void)
{
    // Configure pin for output.
    SET_BIT_HI(DDRB, 0);
    SET_BIT_LO(PORTB, 0);

    // off->red, off->green, off->blue
    RGB_t rgb[3] = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
    WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
    _delay_ms(PAUSE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        rgb[0].r += 1; 
        rgb[1].g += 1; 
        rgb[2].b += 1; 
        WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
        _delay_ms(DELAY);
    }

    // loop forever.
    for (;;) {
        // red->yellow, green->cyan, blue->magenta    
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].g += 1; 
            rgb[1].b += 1; 
            rgb[2].r += 1; 
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // yellow->green, cyan->blue, magenta->white
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].r -= 1; 
            rgb[1].g -= 1; 
            rgb[2].g += 1; 
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // green->cyan, blue->magenta, white->off
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].b += 1; 
            rgb[1].r += 1; 
            rgb[2].r -= 1; 
            rgb[2].g -= 1; 
            rgb[2].b -= 1; 
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // cyan->blue, magenta->white, off->red
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].g -= 1;
            rgb[1].g += 1;
            rgb[2].r += 1;
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // blue->magenta, white->off, red->yellow
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].r += 1;
            rgb[1].r -= 1;
            rgb[1].g -= 1;
            rgb[1].b -= 1;
            rgb[2].g += 1;
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // magenta->white, off->red, yellow->green
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].g += 1;
            rgb[1].r += 1;
            rgb[2].r -= 1;
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // white->off, red->yellow, green->cyan
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].r -= 1;
            rgb[0].g -= 1;
            rgb[0].b -= 1;
            rgb[1].g += 1;
            rgb[2].b += 1;
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);
        }
        // off->red, yellow->green, cyan->blue
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            rgb[0].r += 1;
            rgb[1].r -= 1;
            rgb[2].g -= 1;
            WS2811RGB(rgb, ARRAYLEN(rgb));
            _delay_ms(DELAY);

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `#include <stdint.h>` to bring in the definition of `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef WS2811_h
#define WS2811_h

/** missing an #endif here, (most likely) */

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <WS2811.h>
```

The missing endif causes errors further down.

```
expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '__attribute__' before 'r'
```

This type of error is usually caused by some earlier error, often with the #includes. You missed an #endif, but it can also happen when files include each other improperly. As with any macro errors, they are difficult to track down.